# Mongodb: Unable to return selected data from findOne {engine: 1}

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

How do I add a second parameter {engine: 1, _id: 0} to findOne to only return the engine array {make: "Acrua", model: "CL", year: "1997"}. All of the documents in this collection are unique. Should I be using find instead of findOne. I only want to access one document and send the engine array to the client.

```
[
  {
    make: "Acura",
    model: null,
    year: null,
    engine: ["2.0L", "2.8L"]
  },
  {
    make: "Acura",
    model: "CL",
    year: null,
    engine: ["3.2L", "4.0L"]
  },
  {
    make: "Acura",
    model: "CL",
    year: "1997",
    engine: ["2.2L", "3.0L"]
  }
]


app.get("/ajax_/:tab/:category/:make/:model/:year", function (req, res) {
  db.collection("Autos_").findOne({make: req.params.make, model: params.model, year: req.params.year}, function(err, result) {

    if (result) {
      console.log(result);
    }
  });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

What does 'result' look like when you log it to the console? You could just select out the property value you're looking for and return it that way. According to the MongoDB documentation:

> **The findOne Result Document**
>    You cannot apply cursor methods to the
>   result of findOne() because a single document is returned. You have
>   access to the document directly:
>
> ```
> var myDocument = db.bios.findOne();
>
> if (myDocument) {
>    var myName = myDocument.name;
>
>    print (tojson(myName));
> }
> ```
>
> **Specify the Fields to Return** 
>   The following operation finds a document
>   in the bios collection and returns only the name, contribs and _id
>   fields:
>
> ```
> db.bios.findOne(
>     { },
>     { name: 1, contribs: 1 }
> )
> ```

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/

Answer (score 0):

your parameters may be undefined for some reasons so you have to explicitly set them to `null`. 
Projecting only engine as `{_id:0, engine:1}` can project only engine filed. so you can easily return `result.engine` if exists.

```
app.get("/ajax_/:tab/:category/:make/:model/:year", function (req, res) {

   let make = req.params.make? req.params.make : null ;
   let model = req.params.model? req.params.model : null;
   let year = req.params.year ? req.params.year : null;

   db.collection("Autos_").findOne(
            {make: make, model: model, year: year},
            {_id:0, engine:1},
            function(err, result) {
                     if( err ) {
                           // internal error
                           throw new Error( err);
                     }
                     if (result) {
                          console.log(result.engine);
                     }
            });
})
```